# Having trouble with binding an entity in Blazor

Tags: c#, web-applications, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I am trying to build an ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor web app. I have two entities with a one-to-many relationship.

There is one portfolio that has many securities.

Portfolio entity

```
public class Portfolio
{
    [Key]
    public int PortfolioId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string NameOfPortfolio { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    public virtual ICollection<Security>? Securities { get; set; }
}
```

Security entity

```
public class Security
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string SecurityName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required]
    public float Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int StockesOwned { get; set; } = 0;
    [Required]
    public float StocksValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeObtained { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public string? Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    
    public Portfolio Portfolio { get; set; }
}
```

The `Security` must have a `Portfolio`, but a portfolio may not have a security.

I am trying whenever I want to add a security I must specify the portfolio that contains that security. I am trying to bind the `security.Portfolio` to a `Portfolio` and I can not implement it correctly.

Whenever I try to bind it that way

```
<div class="row w-100">
    <div class="col-6">
        Portfolio
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" >
            <option value="" bind=@Security.Portfolio>Select Portfolio</option>
            @foreach (var portfolio in Portfolios)
            {
                <option value="@portfolio.PortfolioId">@portfolio.NameOfPortfolio</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

It returns an error 400 and it mentions that the portfolio is required

Also here is the service in the client

```
public async Task CreateSecurity(Security security)
{
    var response = await _http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/security", security);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ServiceResponse<int>>();

        if (!(result?.Success ?? false))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResponse<int>>> CreateSecurity(Security security)
{
    var result = await _securityService.CreateSecurityAsync(security);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

The service in the server

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<int>> CreateSecurityAsync(Security security)
{
    _context.Securities.Add(security);
    int result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return new ServiceResponse<int>
        {
            Data = result,
            Success = result > 0,
            Message = "The" + security.SecurityName + "has been saved!"
        };
}
```

Sorry if I misspelled something or did something wrong. I am new to this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you are trying to bind on a normal HTML element, and on top of that, you are binding to the `option` element:

```
...
        <select class="form-control">
            <option value="" bind=@Security.Portfolio>Select Portfolio</option>
            @foreach (var portfolio in Portfolios)
            {
                <option value="@portfolio.PortfolioId">@portfolio.NameOfPortfolio</option>
            }
```

#### Solution 1

Your `Security` class requires a foreign key to bind against. So add this property to your `Security` class:

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(Portfolio))] //Add the Portfolio namespace like nameof(MyNameSpace.Portfolio)
public int PortfolioId { get; set; } //Make sure this property name matches the column name in the Security table in the database.
```

You need to set the value on the change event of the `select` element:

Implement the following:

```
<select class="form-control" @onchange="@OnPortfolioChange">
    <option value="">Select Portfolio</option>
    @foreach (var portfolio in Portfolios)
    {
        <option value="@portfolio.PortfolioId" selected="@portfolio.Id == Security.PortfolioId">@portfolio.NameOfPortfolio</option>
    }
</select>

@code {
    void OnPortfolioChange(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(args.Value?.ToString(), out int portfolioId))
            Security.PortfolioId = portfolioId;
        else
            Security.PortfolioId = null;
    }
}
```

### Solution 2

Like the first solution, but you don't add the extra property to the `Security` class. Instead you need to make your `OnPortfolioChange` this:

```
void OnPortfolioChange(ChangeEventArgs args)
{
    if (int.TryParse(args.Value?.ToString(), out int portfolioId))
        Security.Portfolio = Portfolios.First(p => p.PortfolioId == portfolioId);
    else
        Security.Portfolio = null;
}
```

With that your `option` element's `selected` attribute will look like this:

```
selected="@portfolio.Id == Security.Portfolio?.Id"
```

#### Recommendation

Since you are using the normal HTML elements, I suggest creating a generic component that does your casting in a standard manner that can be reused when required.

Comment: I tried to do the second solution but it gave me the same error, when trying to add the Portfolio to the Security in the client.

Comment: Debug and check your object before the `PostAsJsonAsync` method invocation. Does it contain a populated `Portfolio` object?

Answer (score 0):

The bind=@Security.Portfolio is likely supposed to be on the  tag instead.

Also, I'm not sure if you can bind the whole Portfolio object to the option value.

When you are submitting the model, I would suggest you get the Portfolio by the selected id and putting it on the Security model manually before committing it through the api.